# Rails: Submitting a boolean field through a dropdown menu in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean, simple-form, dropdown

I have a `simple_form` that has a dropdown for a boolean attribute.

```
<option value="0">None</option>
<option value="1">Yes</option>
```

Is this the proper way of submitting a boolean attribute, or should I submit it as `"true"` / `"false"`?

My model does not seem to accept `1` as `true`, it seems...

Answer (score 1):

Use value `true/false` should work for boolean attributes.

So the html will be like:

```
  <option value="false">None</option>
  <option value="true">Yes</option>
```

Or using rails helper:

```
= f.select your_attribute_name, [['None', false], ['Yes', true]]
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using a checkbox or radio-buttons with simpleform setting the `as: :boolean`, `checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false`  It makes the intentions clearer to both the user and any developer that may end up collaborating with you on this.

As for using booleans in a dropdown you could always add a before_save callback in your model that deals with this attribute where it converts the incoming 0 or 1 to true/false first.